# NodeJS App Deployment Error in Heroku via Github Push

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my app in Heroku server to be available in my customized domain name. Everything builds locally, but When I try to deploy in Heroku, the following error pops up. Please help.

This is my build log:

```
        -----> Node.js app detected

     -----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false

    -----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 12.x...
   Downloading and installing node 12.16.3...
   Using default npm version: 6.14.4

    -----> Restoring cache
   Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
   Module installation may take longer for this build

   -----> Installing dependencies
   Installing node modules
   npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
   npm ERR! Invalid tag name "[object Object]": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.vvKxN/_logs/2020-05-23T20_24_41_347Z-debug.log
   -----> Build failed

   We're sorry-this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   Some possible problems:

   - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed

Comment: Could you post the full log as indicated in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you have not mentioned `npm` and `node` version in the `package.json` file.

```
"engines": {
    "npm": "x",
    "node": "y"
}
```

replace x and y with your version of `npm` and `node`.
`node -v` and `npm -v` would provide you with your versions.

Answer (score 1):

You have possible problem 'Node version not specified in package.json'. You need to describe what version of node and npm or yarn you have using.

[Why is my Node.js build failing because of an invalid semver requirement?](https://help.heroku.com/0ZIOF3ST/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-an-invalid-semver-requirement) might help.